# Unity falling platform passes through ground while falling

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I got a Cube with a box collider and a trigger on it. When the player stands on it, it falls down.

I want the platform to destroy itself after colliding with something and before that, instantiate itself at its starting position.

So my code looks this:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
{
    if (col.CompareTag("Player"))
        isFalling = true;
}

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
{
    if (!col.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        Instantiate(gameObject, startPosition, startRotation);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}

void Update()
{
    if (isFalling)
    {
        fallingSpeed += Time.deltaTime / 20;
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - fallingSpeed, transform.position.z);
    }
}
```

Well when my platform crashes down, it just passes through the ground. There is even no collision detected.

Does someone got a hint for me?

Answer (score 2):

So I just got my mistake.

The platform got no rigidbody attached. Therefore it was not able to collide with the ground.

This is my new code:

```
private void Start()
    {
        data.PlatformRigid.useGravity = false; // Disable the gravity to make it stay in the air
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {
        if (!data.Activated) // just do this 1 time 
        {
            if (col.CompareTag("Player")) // just start executing the following code if the colliding object is the player
            {
                data.Activated = true; // don't execute this code a second time
                data.PlatformRigid.useGravity = true; // start falling
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
    {
        if (!col.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            Instantiate(gameObject, data.StartPosition, data.StartRotation); // Create itself at default
            Destroy(gameObject); // Destroy itself
        }
    }
```

I don't need to calculate the fallspeed in the update anymore. I just disable the gravity and enable it, when the player hits the platform.

Answer (score 0):

If your collider is set to trigger, it won't fire the `OnCollisionEnter` event. Instead, put your code in the `OnTriggerEnter` like this:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
{
    if (col.CompareTag("Player")) {
        isFalling = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Instantiate(gameObject, startPosition, startRotation);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: No my platform got a collider and a second collider with a trigger